# Using composer in child theme

Tags: php, composer-php, spreadsheet

I am using `PHP 7.1.8` and I have setup `wordpress 4.9.8`.

I am trying to read data from a spreadsheet using `composer require google/apiclient:^2.0` within my child directory. My `composer.json` looks like the following:

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "2.0"
    }
}
```

My child-theme is located within the following directory:

```
themes
└───child-theme
    ├───css
    ├───inc
    ├───js
    ├───template-parts
    └───vendor
        ├───composer
        ├───firebase
        ├───google
        ├───guzzlehttp
        ├───monolog
        ├───phpseclib
        └───psr
            ├───http-message
            │   └───src
            └───log
                └───Psr
                    └───Log
                        └───Test
```

Within my `functions.php` file I am trying to load the library as the following:

```
if ( file_exists( get_theme_file_path() . '/vendor/autoload.php' ) ) {
    require get_theme_file_path() . '/vendor/autoload.php';
}
...
$client = new \Google_Client(); <-- here I get an error
```

However, the last line `$client = new \Google_Client();` gives me an error, where I do not have any further infos about the error.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What error it gave. .can you paste the error in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this code should be in function.php of your child-theme, you can be assure that vendor folder and autoload file will be always present.

So you can just write it like this.

```
require get_theme_file_path() . '/vendor/autoload.php';
...
$client = new \Google_Client();
```

If there is no autoload.php file present, then it will throw error and you can be sure to always run "composer install".

If this code is not in function.php of your child-theme, then you can attach "require" file code to some action in function.php of your child-theme and use Google_Client anywhere. Just make sure to take care of priorities.